# Bootstrap tooltip container="body" scroll issue

Tags: bootstrap-4, tooltip

I used bootstrap tooltip inside of a dropdown menu. I got that dropdown inside hide tooltip issue.

So I solve that with `container="body"`.

Now I have another issue. That issue is If scroll with hover in tooltip selector element then the tooltip content go to the top.

Refer to the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a solution to this problem. That's if the mouse hovers the tooltip selector element then add a script for that element hover in & out trigger event to remove & add body scroll. Example below:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('body').css('overflow-y', 'scroll')
    }
}, 'YOUR_TOOLTIP_SELECTOR');
```